# trying to connect to socket using xmlsockets cause "Object #<Object> has no method 'SetVariable'"

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, xmlsocket

Im trying to connect to a tcp socket using xmlsocket:

```
    var xmls = new XMLSocket();

    function connect() {
        xmls.onConnect = function(success) {
            if(success)
                connected = true;
        };
        xmls.connect("localhost", 18757);
    };

    setTimeout(connect, 1500);
```

but when the browser tries to perform xmls.connect I get the exception:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'SetVariable'
__XMLSocket.connect

I guess because it tries to do:

```
    __flash.SetVariable("__serverPort",port);
```

I tried to find the problem but I can't find something about it and Im clueless with flash. any ideas?

Comment: Post your HTML/JS code where you embed the SWF and attempt to communicate with it from JS.

Comment: I've decided to go with http traffic which I love&familiar with, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing own constructor in inner function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113004/referencing-own-constructor-in-inner-function)