# Referencing own constructor in inner function

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, actionscript, closures, flash-player-11

Here's a toy example distilled from a complex class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public function MyClass() {
         trace('Created');
    }

    public static function makeObjectAsync(callback:Function):void {
        inner();

        function inner():void {
            var object:MyClass = new MyClass(); // line 10
            callback(object);
        }
    }
}
```

After calling the static function:

```
MyClass.makeObjectAsync(function(object:Myclass):void { ... })
```

the following run-time exception occurs at line 10:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

Why is this, and what can I do about it?

#### Edit

It appears that `new (MyClass)()` works. Now I'm possibly more confused.

Answer (score 1):

Not too clear on the WHY to be honnest. It has to do with the scope inherited by anonymous functions, depending on how they are declared.

I have 2 solutions for you though.

1. If your makeObject method was not static, it would work.
2. Declare your anonymous function the other way :

   ```
   public static function makeObjectAsync(callback:Function):void {
       var inner : Function = function():void {
           var object:MyClass = new MyClass();
           callback(object);
       };

       inner();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call your variable "**object**". Why do you nested your inner function? Why don't you just:

```
public static function makeObjectAsync(callback:Function):void {
    callback(new MyClass());
}
```

Or if you really want that nested function:

```
public static function makeObjectAsync(callback:Function):void {
    inner();

    function inner():void {
        callback(new MyClass());
    }
}
```

And you can't recall the class' constructor again, use a function which is called in the constructor then call it again. With this you aren't referencing the constructor but creating a new instance of the class.

Comment: Sigh. It's a simple example to illustrate the problem - not the real code I was working on.

Comment: And your suggestion with the nested function throws exactly the same exception.

Comment: How do you call the "makeObjectAsync" function?

Comment: `MyClass.makeObjectAsync(doStuffWithObject)`, from a different class in the same package.